# iOS: Distribution of iOS app for beta testing / TestFlight upload

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, testflight, udid

I have build my app with xcode 8.3. Now I need/ to distribute(send) application build to other team members (application tester as well as client for beta testing) to test our app in their apple (iPhone/iPad) devices. I've searched and read, so many tutorials/QAs but couldn't got a tutorial for beginners(novice level developer) How to connect the certificates, provision profile and UDIDs and how to distribute app for beta testing.

Can someone help me, how to connect certificate and tester's devices with my app. Any help for iOS beginners would be very welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through following steps (Details of each steps is linked with Apple guideline)

1. [Configuring Your Xcode Project for Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW1)

   - Configure Identity and Team Settings
   - Set Bundle ID
   - [Create Team Provisioning Profile.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW7)
   - Assign the Xcode Project to a Team
   - Select a signing identity
2. [Maintaining Identifiers, Devices, and Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW1)

   - Register App IDs
   - Register Devices Using Your Developer Account
   - Create Development/Ad Hoc/Production Provisioning Profiles
   - Download Provisioning Profiles in Xcode
3. [Export Your App for Testing (iOS, tvOS, watchOS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1)

   - Register Test Device
   - Archive Your App
   - Export Your App for Testing Outside the Store
4. [Distributing Your App Using TestFlight (iOS, tvOS, watchOS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight.html)